# Running zend tool in windows system

Tags: zend-framework, zend-tool

I am trying to learn zend framework. I am using the quick start tutorial provided at the site for this. While, I am going on, I noticed that the zend tool commands provided at that site, is not intended for windows system.

The point I am stuck in is

```
% zf configure db-adapter \
> 'adapter=PDO_SQLITE&dbname=APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook.db"' \
> production
```

How to run this command in CMD? I have tried several variations but they all give wrong output. Also, it would be great full if you could point me to a reference from which I could learn zend tool commands for windows.

Comment: Explain the close vote please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that it is not intended for Windows. With every version of Zend Framework you get a zf.bat for Windows! The commands are exactly the same for all OSs. So the only thing you have to do to make it work is to add the path to the ...\bin direcotry where the zf.bat is located to your windows system path.

[**Zend_Tool_Framework Programmer's Reference Guide**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html)

Comment: Please read the question clearfully. I have mentioned `zend tool commands provided at that site, is not intended for windows` not the zend tool itself.

Comment: of course if you enter the command exactly in the way you posted it, it won't work on any platform. but I assume you don't.

Comment: I have found the correct one. So you are the one who is wrong. Check my answer to find the command for windows.

Comment: Oops.. I thought I posted the answer. Turns out it was asking for spam verification.

Comment: May be he is write about the slashes part but not for others.